# Advance flash via javascript

Tags: javascript, flash

I've been reading that I can simply advance my flash movie using the js play method:

```
object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="260" height="373" id="myFlashMov">
      <param name="movie" value="myflashmovie.swf" />
      <param name="play" value="true" />
      <param name="loop" value="false" />
      <param name="menu" value="false" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="scale" value="showall" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
      <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="sameDomain" 

var player1 = document.getElementById("myFlashMov");
 player1.play();
```

But the browser continues to say play is not a function.  Do I have to do something specific within the flash to register this js function?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the ExternalInterface class. See the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

The ExternalInterface class allows for a two way communication between AS3 & JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var player1 = document.getElementById("myFlashMov");
player1.Play();
```

The capital P should do the trick. It works for me.

Edit:

You may also need to put the `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain"/>` tag inside your object-tag. I am not sure that this is needed, but it doesn't hurt